# Drupal: Creating anchor only link with l()

Tags: drupal

I'd like to output this

```
<a href='#namedanchor'>link</a>
```

using the l() function, so that the link just jumps to an anchor on the current page.

I expected this to work

```
l('link', '',  array('fragment' => 'namedanchor'));
```

but it creates an absolute link to `www.example.com/#namedanchor` instead of `www.example.com/currentpage#namedanchor`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to create a link with just the fragment, you need to "trick" the url function a bit. As it will append the basepath to all internal urls, `''` will become `http://example.com`.

What you need to do is to set the external option to true:

```
l('link', '',  array('fragment' => 'namedanchor', 'external' => TRUE));
```

This will give the desired

```
<a href='#namedanchor'>link</a>
```

Alternative you could give the full url like Jeremy suggests.

Comment: probably should add `t()` function around the first argument in `l()`, right?

Answer (score 3):

To create an anchor using l():

```
$path = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '<front>';
l(t('link text'), $path, array('attributes' => array('name' => 'name-of-anchor')));
```

This will output:

```
<a href="/path/to/currentpage" name="name-of-anchor">link text</a>
```

Then, to link to this using l():

```
$path = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '<front>';
l(t('link to anchor'), $path, array('fragment' => 'name-of-anchor'));
```

This will output:

```
<a href="/path/to/currentpage#name-of-anchor">link to anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation for [l](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l/6)

It dosn't look like it will by default use the current page when no path is defined. So you should call it like this:

```
l('link', 'currentpage',  array('fragment' => 'namedanchor'));
```